# Read XML with PySpark

Tags: python, xml, apache-spark, databricks

I'm trying to read XML with PySpark, but I have some problems.

I'm running this code:

```py
df_cli = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.xml').options(rowTag='Cli').load('MyFile.txt', schema = schema_xml)
```

and MyFile.txt:

```xml
<Cli Tp="1" Cd="8338" Autorzc="S">
  <Op Contrt="1" NatuOp="01" Mod="1304">
    <Venc v110="   123" v120="   123"/>
  </Op>
  <Op Contrt="2" NatuOp="01" Mod="1304">
    <Venc v110="   123" v120="   123"/>
  </Op>
</Cli>

<Cli Tp="2" Cd="8568" Autorzc="N">
  <Op Contrt="3" NatuOp="01" Mod="1304">
    <Venc v110="   123" v120="   123"/>
  </Op>
  <Op Contrt="4" NatuOp="01" Mod="1304">
    <Venc v110="   123" v120="   123"/>
  </Op>
</Cli>
```

Schema:

```py
schema_xml = StructType([
    StructField("@Autorzc", StringType(), True),
    StructField("@Cd", StringType(), True),
    StructField("@Tp", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Op",
            StructType([
                    StructField("@Contrt", StringType(), True),
                    StructField("@Mod", StringType(), True),
                    StructField("@NatuOp", StringType(), True),
                    StructField("Venc",
                            StructType([
                                    StructField("@v110", StringType(), True),
                                    StructField("@v120", StringType(), True)
                            ])
                    )
            ])
    )
])
```

When I run this code, my output is that:

```py
Row(@Autorzc=u'S', @Cd=u'8338', @Tp=u'1', Op=Row(@Contrt=u'2', @Mod=u'1304', @NatuOp=u'01', Venc=Row(@v110=u'   123', @v120=u'   123)))
Row(@Autorzc=u'N', @Cd=u'8568', @Tp=u'2', Op=Row(@Contrt=u'4', @Mod=u'0202', @NatuOp=u'01', Venc=Row(@v110=u'   123', @v120=u'   123)))
```

The result is getting only last 'Op' in each 'Cli', but I expected to get all 'Op' inside each 'Cli' in a list, like this:

```py
Row(@Autorzc=u'S', @Cd=u'8338', @Tp=u'1', Op=[Row(@Contrt=u'1', @Mod=u'1304', @NatuOp=u'01', Venc=Row(@v110=u'   123', @v120=u'   123)), Row(@Contrt=u'2', @Mod=u'1304', @NatuOp=u'01', Venc=Row(@v110=u'   123', @v120=u'   123))])
Row(@Autorzc=u'N', @Cd=u'8568', @Tp=u'2', Op=[Row(@Contrt=u'3', @Mod=u'1304', @NatuOp=u'01', Venc=Row(@v110=u'   123', @v120=u'   123)), Row(@Contrt=u'4', @Mod=u'1304', @NatuOp=u'01', Venc=Row(@v110=u'   123', @v120=u'   123))])
```

Obs: In my original file I can have 1, 2, 3...N 'Op' and each 'Op' has only 1 'Venc'.

I'm using [this documentation](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml/tree/branch-0.3).